# split before GROUP BY soql

Tags: apex, soql, aggregate, group-by, split

I have a field which has the values in the format [5 digits-3 digits]

> 12345-123
>
> 34646-345
>
> 12345-133

I want to Group BY this field with the just the 5 digit number only (not the complete field).  How do I do it?

[expected result: 12345 should be grouped by together]

Comment: Create a formula, `LEFT(MyField__c, 5)` and group by that.

Comment: How many records are you working with?

Comment: @AdrianLarson, does that work with large data sets?  My understanding is that because formulas are calculated at run time, Salesforce will have to retrieve all records and calculate the formula field, then perform the relevant SOQL.  In large data sets, this could be quite inefficient.  Perhaps implementing it as a workflow rule might help.

Comment: Its a large dataset over 100,000

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy looks like you are looking for this feature https://success.salesforce.com/ideaView?id=08730000000BrHYAA0  Sorry currently not available.. you have to go with Adrian Larson approach or any other.

Answer (score 2):

Create a field to contain your first five digits. Populate it via `Workflow Rule`/`Process Builder`/`Apex Trigger`. The contents will be:

```
LEFT(My9DigitField__c, 5)
```

Or alternatives in Apex:

```
My9DigitField__c.substringBefore('-');
My9DigitField__c.substring(0, 5);
```

Unfortunately you will need to backfill this new field as well. I recommend using dataloader for such an exercise.

Comment: was looking for solution without a new field. thanks anyways!

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy Then the answer is: it's not possible with `SOQL`.

Comment: @sfdcFanBoy Are you still stuck?

Comment: Went for workaround (looping through the list results and then truncating it through code) .  But not through a new field.